# Reg. Permission request for Delphi android application

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing android mobile application and for the compatibility of Android API 26, I have used [this link](https://www.delphiworlds.com/2018/05/targeting-android-8-and-higher/) for changing the target version to 26 and I have tried to implement request permission using [demo app](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/AndroidDangerousPermissions). But, when I have used the sample code in my application, I'm getting the proper request for Storage(android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and after specifying allow, I'm not getting any response and my application is getting hanged but the Storage permission was enabled. Then, again if I'm starting the restarting the application, the application was working properly. Can I use some other method for the permission request. Please suggest solution.

Comment: Delphi 10.2 and earlier are not natively compatible with Android API 26. That is coming in the next major version, Delphi 10.3.

Comment: But when I'm running the application separately, the application was running successfully.

Comment: You should use the implementation from this article instead:  https://www.delphiworlds.com/2018/06/targeting-android-8-and-higher-continued, as it does not rely on "overriding" the native activity